# How to write a word letter by letter?

Tags: javascript, animation, text

how a word is written letter by letter. it should appear letter after another with some delay. here is the code.

```
var txt = 'animating text';
var current = 0;

function write(text){
   var elem = document.getElementById('target');
   if (current < text.length){
      elem.textContent = elem.textContent + text.charAt(current);
      current++;
      wait(100);
   }
}

Write(txt);
```

Comment: How do you determine if the user has read the letter or not? What is the end goal? What have you tried till now?

Comment: it is nothing to do with user. the only thing do here is letters are printed one by one. actually it is very attracting if you see my link. as an example take the sentence "this is a test".
then 'T' is displayed first. after 100ms 'h' appears and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you write one character at a time and have a timeout in beteween. [Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jS6gB/3/) and below the code

```
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat ante sed fringilla bibendum. In quam elit, rutrum quis adipiscing id, iaculis eu ipsum. Morbi faucibus lectus at ante feugiat dignissim. In turpis turpis, placerat in fringilla eget, sodales blandit lacus. Vivamus tempor blandit mauris nec semper. Sed cursus metus sed justo cursus bibendum. Maecenas ornare sem sed lacinia auctor. Nulla sapien dolor, faucibus vitae dapibus in, commodo id est. Sed a ipsum laoreet, convallis lacus eu, hendrerit magna.';

// Variable for current position
var curr = 0;

var Write = function write(){

    // Find the target element to write to
    var elem = document.getElementById('target');

    // Append next character into the text content
    elem.textContent = elem.textContent + text.charAt(curr);

    // Update the current position
    curr++;

    // if we're not yet in the end of the string
    // we have a little (20ms) pause before we write the next character
    if (curr < text.length)
        window.setTimeout(write, 20);
};

Write(); // And of course we have to call the function
```

Comment: This is the exactly thing I asked. perfect answer.